# Input tab character from Shiny and supply it to a function

Tags: r, shiny, escaping, delimiter, readr

I'm trying to get a delimiter character input from the end user, which can be a tab character `\t`, a carriage return character `\r` or any other character like a newline character `\n`. I want to then pass this character on to [read_delim](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.3.1/topics/read_delim) function from `readr` package so that a file is read with the proper delimiter. However, when I enter say `"\t"` in the `textInput`, it gets parsed as `"\\t"` (with an escaped `"\"`) and I cannot directly pass it on to the `read_delim` function. How do I achieve this? I do not want to hardcode this since there can be many delimiters with escape characters. Below is a reproducible example of what I'm trying to do :

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    textInput("delimiter", "Enter Delimiter")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    actionButton("send_input", "Send Input")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$send_input, {
    print(input$delimiter) # prints "\\t"
    table_data <- readr::read_delim(file = "data.tsv",
                                    delim = input$delimiter) # does not work
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try removing the first `"\"`  with `sub()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by Edward, I can remove the first `"\"` via:

```
eval(parse(text=sub("\\", "", deparse(input$delimiter), fixed=TRUE)))
```

Passing the above as delimiter works directly.